# change position of an array of a larger array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array like matrix using `numpy` like this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

the desired array is like this:

```
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],])
```

description: first and second arrays move to the end of the matrix.
I tried something with changing `a` to a `list` and used `append` and `del` functions and then convert it to a `numpy array` but it could not be something good to write in python.
is there any function to replace an array position in a larger array-like matrix in `numpy`?

Comment: Just use `np.roll(a, -n, axis-0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so easy if you use this simple line of code. no function and other things are needed.
simply use `numpy.roll`. [see explanations here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

```
# Assume your matrix is named a.
>>> a

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])

>>> np.roll(a,-(n % len(a)),axis=0)

array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Function that takes the number of rotations

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [14]: def rotate(n):
...:         n = n%len(a)
...:         return np.concatenate([a[n:], a[:n]])

In [13]: rotate(2)
Out[13]:
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])
```

What if you give `n` more than the length of the array? It's handled - `n = n%len(a)`

```
In [16]: rotate(9)
Out[16]:
array([[17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Another solution given in comments is `roll()` method.

```
In [6]: a
Out[6]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [7]: def rotate(n):
   ...:     n = n % len(a)
   ...:     return np.roll(a,-n,axis=0)
   ...:

In [8]: rotate(8)
Out[8]:
array([[13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [9]: rotate(2)
Out[9]:
array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])
```